# How to capture R Shiny text input of variable name for analysis

Tags: r, shiny

Newbie to R and working through simple R Shiny examples for learning purposes. The following program enables user to upload a delimited data file, at which point head() displays first few rows. I also want to allow use to input in a text input the name of a variable in the file to generate a frequency. How can i capture the text input and reference it in the server section?  You can see i have commented out a line where i manually enter the field and it works fine.

I've sifted through quite a few examples using textinput, but all were facing different issues than i could find. I do apologize if a post already has the help i seek.  Thanks in advance.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  splay <- reactive({

    req(input$file1)

    df.raw <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)

    info <- list(df.raw=df.raw)
    return(info)
   })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    if(input$disp == "head") { return(head(splay()$df.raw)) }
    else { return(splay()$df.raw) }
   })

  observe({
      varname <- renderText({input$frqvar})
  })

  output$jason <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$file1)) { return() }
    #table(splay()$df.raw$tx)
    table(splay()$df.raw$varname())
  })

  output$caption1 <- renderText({
    if (is.null(input$file1)) { return() }
    paste("Listing of Uploaded Data and Frequency of ",input$frqvar ,"Variable")
  })

} #this ends the server function

#ui=user interface portion
#place elements in the fluid page section to layout the page
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", multiple = FALSE, accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")),

      # Horizontal line
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header 
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator 
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      # Input: Select quotes 
      radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                   choices = c(None = "",
                               "Double Quote" = '"',
                               "Single Quote" = "'"),
                   selected = '"'),

      # Horizontal line 
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display 
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head"),

      textInput("frqvar", 
                   label = h1("Variable to run Freq"), 
                   value = " " ),
      actionButton("action", label="Submit")
   ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      textOutput("caption1"),
      tableOutput("contents"),
      tableOutput("jason")

      #tableOutput("")
      )
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example using one of R's built-in dataset, with a twist. Having users type in the name of the variable will lead to a lot of errors and thus a lot of work  on your end to catch those errors. Ideally, after users have uploaded their dataset, you generate a dropdown menu of the variable names that can be selected.

Before explaining the above, you can access any input in your `server` function with `input$id`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("id", "label"),
    verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output){
    output$out <- renderPrint({
        input$id
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now, for generating executing what you are after but with a `selectInput` (drop down menu).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", "select a dataset", choices = c("cars", "mtcars")),
  uiOutput("dropdown"),
  verbatimTextOutput("head"),
  plotOutput("hist")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    if(input$dataset == "cars")
      cars
    else
      mtcars
  })

  output$dropdown <- renderUI({
    selectInput("variables", "Select a variable", names(data()))
  })

  output$head <- renderPrint({
    head(data())
  })

  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(data()[[input$variables]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnCoene for the assist.  This helped a great deal.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code with small modifications of your `server`function with dependency of `submit` button reactive environment.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
  splay <- reactive({
  req(input$file1)
  df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
  info <- list(df = df)
  return(info)
  })
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    if (input$disp == "head") { return(head(splay()$df)) }
    else {return(splay()$df) }
  })

  freq <- eventReactive(input$action,{
      return(splay()$df[[input$frqvar]])
  })
  observeEvent(input$action,{
    output$jason <- renderTable({
      if (is.null(input$file1)) { return() }
      else {table(freq()) }
      })
    })

  output$caption1 <- renderText({
    if (is.null(input$file1)) { return() }
    paste("Listing of Uploaded Data and Frequency of ",input$frqvar ," Variable")
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to showcase this additional feature that wasn't even my main question.  A number of little improvements make the whole thing better!  Again, much appreciated!